# Angular 2: Expression containing markup

Tags: html, angular, angular2-template

I'm looking for a way to tell Angular to display a value inside an expression that contains markup, and actually use the HTML:

```
{{ value }}

let value = "<span>foobar</span>";
```

So, the `value` variable contains a string with markup, and I want to apply the markup so it is rendered in the page.  So if `value` contained `<b>test</b>`, then on the page, bold text would appear.

Comment: isn't it possible to use {{ value }} inside the `<span>`? Or maybe you can play around with `*ngIf` and create `<span>` if some statement is true or otherwise create `<p>` or whatever you want...

Answer (score 5):

Guess you are looking for `innerHTML`:

```
value: string = "<span>foobar</span>";

<div [innerHTML]="value">
</div>
```

The code above will be rendered to:

```
<div>
    <span>foobar</span>
</div>
```